# /etc/cron.daily/ what this command is doing?

Tags: ubuntu, cron, ubuntu-18.04, cron.daily

Could you help to explain what this command is doing?

```
printf '#!/bin/sh\n\find /opt/traccar/logs -mtime +5 -type f -delete\n' > /etc/cron.daily/traccar-clear-logs && chmod +x /etc/cron.daily/traccar-clear-logs
```

Comment: https://www.traccar.org/clear-history/

Comment: @ceejayoz thanks you so much.